# When I launch Ubuntu it just has a purple screen?

Tags: dual-boot

It goes to a purple screen then black, and doesn't do anything. I am using 12.04 WUBI on my laptop. I'm new to ubuntu so I don't know what to do

Comment: Hardware configuration please?

Comment: Are you asking for my system specs?

Comment: yes, what video card you have and all other hardware that might cause this problems...

Comment: Well it has a dual core 1.8ghz intel celeron, intel integrated graphics, 4gb of RAM, and 320gb hdd. But do you think reinstalling might help?

Answer (score 1):

This fooled me the first time I installed WUBI and it frustrated me for a week. After the screen goes black get a flashlight and shine it an angle at the center of the screen. If you can see the Ubuntu logo it just means that your computer's brightness is low. I tried `nomodeset`, grub editing, external displays and when I got frustrated I banged the keyboard accidentally hitting the brightness and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It could one of a few things:

1. It's possible that WUBI is just taking a long time to boot.  My P4 laptop running at 3GHz took a LONG time to get past the purple screen (~10 minutes).  I knew it wasn't completely dead because the hard drive light was on pretty solid.
2. Alternatively it could be hung in the boot process.  Try hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key and see if any errors are reported during boot-up.
3. Make sure you shut Windows down correctly and it didn't leave the disk in an un-clean state.  Boot into windows and run "chkdsk /r" on the drive where WUBI was installed.
4. If none of those work, you might want to check out the [Troubleshooting section of the Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Troubleshooting).